# Eclipselink 2.4 + JPA + ManyToMany with additional column

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I'm developing a student manager application in Java with JPA entities provided by Eclipselink. I'm trying to implement a many-to-many relationship between two entities for a while, but I ran into some weird exceptions.

My implementations are based on:
[Java persistence Wiki page of ManyToMany relationship](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany#Mapping_a_Join_Table_with_Additional_Columns) and [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878374/how-do-you-set-up-a-many-to-many-relationship-with-junction-table-using-jpa-ecli).

Here is my **Homework.java** file's relevant parts:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "db_homework")
public class Homework {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)    
    private long id;

    ... other fields and connections ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "semester")
    private Collection<SemesterHomework> semesters;

    ... getters/setters ...
}
```

**Semester.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "db_semester")
public class Semester {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)    
    private long id;

    ... other fields and connections ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "homework")
    private Collection<SemesterHomework> homeworks;

    ... getters/setters ...
}
```

**SemesterHomework.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="db_semesterhomework")
@IdClass(SemesterHomeworkPK.class)
public class SemesterHomework {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional=false)  
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="HOMEWORK_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
    private Homework homework;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional=false)  
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="SEMESTER_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
    private Semester semester;

    @Column
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date finishTime;
    ... getters/setters ...
}
```

**SemesterHomeworkPK.java:**

```
public class SemesterHomeworkPK {
    @Id
    @Column(name="SEMESTER_ID")
    private Long semester;
    @Id
    @Column(name="HOMEWORK_ID")
    private Long homework;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object arg0) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        ...
    }

    ... getters/setters ...
}
```

The **exceptions** what i get:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-41] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A non-read-only mapping must be defined for the sequence number field.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(org.bme.amorg.droidhfsite.server.db.Homework --> [DatabaseTable(db_homework)])

Exception [EclipseLink-41] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A non-read-only mapping must be defined for the sequence number field.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(org.bme.amorg.droidhfsite.server.db.Semester --> [DatabaseTable(db_semester)])

Exception [EclipseLink-93] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The table [db_homework] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(org.bme.amorg.droidhfsite.server.db.Semester --> [DatabaseTable(db_semester)])

Exception [EclipseLink-93] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The table [db_semester] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(org.bme.amorg.droidhfsite.server.db.Homework --> [DatabaseTable(db_homework)])
```

The exceptions occur when I try to generate the database tables with Eclipse JPA tools.

Thanks for the help in advance,
Peter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is the only problem, but you got your `mappedBy` attributes wrong.

The list of semesters in `Homework` is mapped by the `homework` field of `SemesterHomework`. Not by the `semester` field.

And the list of homeworks in `Semester` is mapped by the `semester` field of `SemesterHomework`. Not by the `homework` field.

Everything would be much easier if you had a non-composite, autogenerated ID in `SemesterHomework`.